# Java Elastic Search query gives wrong results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a problem with elasticsearch query in Java
This is my code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

for example:
if (myFilter.getTerm1() != null) {
        qb.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("myfield1", myFilter.getTerm1()));
    }

if (myFilter.getTerm2() != null) {
        qb.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("myfield2", myFilter.getTerm2()));
    }

qb.minimumShouldMatch("100%");
SearchRequest request = op.searchRequest(classTarget(MyClass.class));// this just create a new SearchRequest    
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(qb.toString()));
    sourceBuilder.from((pageNumber));
    sourceBuilder.size(pageSize);
    request.source(sourceBuilder);
```

The problem is that this gives me back all the result that matches with  “myfield1 **OR** myfield2”, but I need to have all the result that matches  “myfield1 **AND** myfield2”

For example if I have 2 documents, one with

myfield1 = “Foo” and myfield2 = “Test”

and the other with:

myfield1 = “Elastic” and myfield2 = “Search”

if I made a query with myfield1 = “Foo” and myfield2 = “Search” I expect to have no results, but I have both documents.

I also tried to use “must” instead of “should” and I tried to set the default operator to “AND” in sourceBuilder but in this case I have no results at all, also if the query should return something.

this is the print of "request"

```
Query request: SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[myIndex], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false], types=[data], routing='null', preference='data', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, allowPartialSearchResults=null, source={"from":0,"size":100,"query":{"simple_query_string":{"query":"{\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"should\" : [\n      {\n        \"terms\" : {\n          \"myfield1.keyword\" : [\n            \"foo\"\n          ],\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"terms\" : {\n          \"myfield2.keyword\" : [\n            \"search\"\n          ],\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"minimum_should_match\" : \"100%\",\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","flags":-1,"default_operator":"or","analyze_wildcard":false,"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_prefix_length":0,"fuzzy_max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":1.0}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need AND logic, then you can rule out `should`. You need `must` instead and probably with a `match` query instead of `term` (as I don't think you need exact matching). Try this instead:

```
if (myFilter.getTerm1() != null) {
    qb.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("myfield1", myFilter.getTerm1()));
}

if (myFilter.getTerm2() != null) {
    qb.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("myfield2", myFilter.getTerm2()));
}
```

also remove `qb.minimumShouldMatch("100%");`

Also this `QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(qb.toString())` should result in an error, as you cannot serialize a bool query into a `simple_query_string` query, it's just not meant for that purpose.

Simply change your statement to this one:

```
sourceBuilder.query(qb);
```

If you print out your query you'll see the following, which is most probably not what you want:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "{\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"should\" : [\n      {\n        \"terms\" : {\n          \"myfield1.keyword\" : [\n            \"foo\"\n          ],\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"terms\" : {\n          \"myfield2.keyword\" : [\n            \"search\"\n          ],\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"minimum_should_match\" : \"100%\",\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
      "flags": -1,
      "default_operator": "or",
      "analyze_wildcard": false,
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
      "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed all the "should" with "must" and all the "termsQuery" with "match Query". Also qb.minimumShouldMatch("100%"); deleted. Same reuslts

Comment: Can you show a document that should match, your index mapping as well as which query terms you're sending in the query?

Comment: I don't think it's something related to documents or mapping because before I didn't use Sourcebuilder and it worked, but then I needed it to set 
  sourceBuilder.from(pageNumber );
  sourceBuilder.size(pageSize);

for pagination. So i think it is somethig related to Sourcebuilder BTW thank you for the reply

Comment: In this case, what `pageNumber` and `pageSize` are you sending?

Comment: Another problem is this: `QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(qb.toString())` you cannot serialize a bool query into `simple_query_string`, it just won't work... it should give you an error, by the way.

Comment: I send 1 and 100(or 10) for pageNumber e pageSize.  I have no error with the boolean query serialization :/ I think in case of error I should have no results, but I have(wrong but I have so it makes a query)

Comment: from should be 0, not 1 or you risk missing the first (and only) result.

Comment: `simple_query_string` expects a completely different syntax: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html so you're not getting an error, but you're definitely not sending what you expect. Try to print out the query and you'll see.

Comment: see the edit to my question, I have copied the print of "request"

Comment: sourceBuilder.query(qb); this was the right way to do, thank you very much ):

Comment: I changed back to boolean and termQuery so it is definitely only sourceBuilder problem